# Additional navigation bar in header

Tags: menus, wp-admin, navigation

[image: double navigation bars]

Recently, my site started showing two navigation bars at the top of my page.  They are also the wrong layout. I am fairly new to WordPress.  I have only designed five websites so far.  This is the first time I have encountered this issue.  I am editing through Elementor Pro, and this does not show up when I preview the page, but it shows up when you enter into the website itself.  How can this be fixed?[image]

Comment: You'll have to ask the theme developer and the Elementor development team about this.  Normally if you want to get a good answer on here you should be posting code.  Just looking at those images tells us nothing about what could be causing what or what could have changed within your theme or Elementor.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.